# Output the line number for all string matches within a file

Tags: debugging

```
def line_number(word, fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        number_list = ""
        for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
            if word in line:
                number_list += (str(i)+", ")      
        return number_list[:-2]
```

The function above is suppose to find the line number on a txt file which a matching string occurs. However, for example, if we are searching the string "yes", and we have string "yes" on the 20th line and "eyes" on the 51st line, the function will return line 20 and line 51 because line 51 contains a substring "yes" in "eyes", how can I fix this bug?

Okay, I have solved the problem by changing `if word in line:` to `if word in re.split('(\W+)', line):`

By doing so I split the line into words and punctuation to find the exact match.

But I noticed anohter problem. For example, on `line 159`, there is a sentence of "you you you." the word `you` appear 3 times, the function only counts `you` appear once in `line 159`, and the program prints out:

`you     159`

but I want the function to count it 3 times and prints out:

`you     159, 159, 159`

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: thanks, i have solved the problem, but i noticed there's another problem, can you take a look?

Answer (score 1):

To include duplicate matches on a row, you can do this using [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

> re.**findall**(*pattern*, *string*, *flags*=0)
>
> Return all non-overlapping matches of *pattern* in *string*, as a list of strings

Just replace this:

```
if word in line:
```

with this:

```
for match in re.findall(r'\b' + word + r'\b', line):
```

Comment: thanks a lot!!!! this one totally works, it solves the problem of findding the extra substring, and it counts the whole line!!

Answer (score -1):

Substitute `if word in line` for `if word == line.strip()`.

Comment: it does not work, a word cant be exactly matching with a line, am i correct?

Comment: You are right, each line has a line break (\n) at the end. I edit my answer.

Comment: it doesn't work either, the print fails to display the line number. inspired by your strip() method, i tried to use the slpit() method instead, break the line into words, and find the matches. but it comes out an erro saying "'str' object has no attribute 'slipt'", im sure the "line" is a string type and can be split, could you tell what happened here?

Comment: Well, first of all you are misspelling split :P

Comment: Why are you doing this? `return number_list[:-2]`

Comment: I added a comma and a space between each line number, just for looking clean, but the last line number will have a comma and space at the end too, so I do return number_list[:-2] to get rid of it =P

Comment: Haha, I see... What is exactly the error you get with my solution? I am trying that and works fine.

Comment: It seems like if I replace "in" with "==", the function fails to return any line number, same with my split()method, I can only use "in".

Comment: yes, and using strip()

Comment: That is weird, it works fine for me...

Comment: I'm using the 3.3 version, what version is yours?